# Subgroup of ( C \ {0}, * ) isomorphic to the quotient group ( C \ {0} ) / ( R \ {0} )

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, real-numbers, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

So recently I have been studying group theory and I just really struggle, when it comes to homomorphisms. So, I thought I would tackle some problems and it went ok for a while until I came across this problem:

Let $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$ be a group. Show that $f:(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )→(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$ given by, $z→(\frac{z}{|z|})^2$ is a group homomorphism. Find a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$ that is isomorphic to the quotient group $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )\text{ / }(\mathbb{R}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$

Now, proving the group homorphism wasn't particularly hard and $(\mathbb{R}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$  is clearly a normal subgroup of $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$. I also know that the quotient group $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )\text { / }\ker(f)$ is isomorphic to the $Im(f)$. But how does that help me find a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$ that is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )\text{ / }(\mathbb{R}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$?

Would I need to find the kernel of f, so all elements $z$ element of $(\mathbb{C}\text{ \ }\{0\}, * )$, for which $(\frac{z}{|z|})^2 = 1$?

Comment: Yes. Did you find a kernel? What is it? Is it is equal to $(\mathbb{R}\text{ \ }\{0\},*)$ ? Then $Im(f)$ is your required group.

Comment: I just edited your question and used some LaTeX in it. See here for how to use LaTeX: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/168676